# Number of nodes and channels in Lightning Network?

Tags: lightning-network, tools, ln-topology

**(1)** Is there any tool by which we can know the current number of nodes (participants as payer/payee) and number of channels in Lightning Network with an accurate estimation?

**(2)** As a more advanced query, is it also possible to know the topology of this graph? (vertices as participants and edges as channels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since https://rompert.com/recksplorer/ apparently is no longer available ([**screen shot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9aJ1.jpg)), I add the following link including a mostly visual collection of the Lightning Network:

https://gist.github.com/bretton/798ec38165ffabc719d91e0f4f67552d

Answer (score 3):

As for (1) yes you can use tools like the recksplorer as suggested by JBaczuk but you can also query the gossip store of your lightning node directly. Each node has to know the entire topology of the network for source based routing. C-Lightning provides a command line interface to retrieve this data.

However nodes can have private channels or be even private themselves. So with the Recksplorer which utilizes the Gossipstore and with the Gossip store you will only get a fraction of the Lightning Network. People Using Bitcoin Lightning Wallet or Eclaire mobile Wallet will currently not be public.

As for (2) I have created an autopilot for c-lightning with the python client library which analyzed the graph with the networkx module of python. you can check out the code at this pull request: https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/pull/1888 This should give you a starting point for doing more statistics about the topology.

Answer (score 1):

You can try recksplorer at https://rompert.com/recksplorer/ to get a node count, or drill down on individual nodes:

[image: Recksplorer]

Source is at: https://github.com/chemicstry/recksplorer

Comment: Thank you ; however  https://rompert.com/recksplorer/ apparently is no longer available [screen shot](https://imgur.com/LOtZi2V).

Comment: recksplorer is working

Answer (score 1):

1. **Amboss** - https://amboss.space/ - Gives stats around Lightning network
   [image]
2. **1ml.com** - https://1ml.com/ - Similar to amboss
   [image]
3. **LN Lighthouse** - https://lnlighthouse.online/ - Helps to group (by capacity) and visualise peers of any node (Disclaimer: I am the front end dev of this app)
   [image]